# How to convert a dictionary which is in string format to tabular dataframe in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an method which return a string and the value is like dictionary. E.g type is string and the return value is:

```
{"firstName":"bb288e8ff56b","lastName":"ae4863bdae026314"}
```

I want to convert this to a dataframe which will have two column firstName and LastName.

For now i am only able to store it as a single column in dataframe using .toDF()

```
val df=Seq(retrunString).toDF("record");
```

Can some one help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the from_json function from Spark's functions package to parse the JSON string into a struct:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import spark.implicits._

val jsonString = """{"firstName":"bb288e8ff56b","lastName":"ae4863bdae026314"}"""

val df = Seq(jsonString).toDF("record")

val schema = StructType(
  Seq(
    StructField("firstName", StringType),
    StructField("lastName", StringType)
  )
)

val parsedDf = df
  .select(from_json(col("record"), schema).as("parsed"))
  .select("parsed.firstName", "parsed.lastName")

parsedDf.show()

+------------+----------------+
|   firstName|        lastName|
+------------+----------------+
|bb288e8ff56b|ae4863bdae026314|
+------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do.. below are two approaches.

```
val jsonString = """{"firstName":"bb288e8ff56b","lastName":"ae4863bdae026314"}"""
```

```
spark.read.json(Seq(jsonString).toDS).show(false)
```

```
+------------+----------------+
|firstName   |lastName        |
+------------+----------------+
|bb288e8ff56b|ae4863bdae026314|
+------------+----------------+
```

```
Seq(jsonString)
.toDF("record")
.withColumn(
   "record", 
    expr(
     "from_json(record, 'struct<firstName: string, lastName:string>')"
    )
)
.select("record.*")
.show(false)
```